# Applications crash when hook LdrLoadDll in delphi

Tags: delphi, dll, hook

I hooked the `LdrLoadDll` to detect all Dlls load in a program.

It's my hook section of code :

```
var
  Old_LdrLoadDll: function(szcwPath: PChar; pdwLdrErr: PULONG;
    pUniModuleName: PUnicodeString; pResultInstance: PPointer)
    : NTStatus; stdcall;
....
```

It work :

```
function New_LdrLoadDll(szcwPath:PChar ; pdwLdrErr: PULONG;
  pUniModuleName: PUnicodeString; pResultInstance: PPointer): NTStatus; stdcall;
begin

  OutputDebugString('New_LdrLoadDll');
  Result := Old_LdrLoadDll(szcwPath, pdwLdrErr, pUniModuleName,
    pResultInstance);
end;
```

But when i add any other command in `New_LdrLoadDll` application was crashed !
I use a Sustainable hook method and i sure the problem isn't for hooking nethod, I test many other APIs and work perfectly expect this !

Any idea ?
{Excuse me for my bad English}

Comment: I can't imagine why would one need to hook `LdrLoadDll` for their own application.

Comment: @TLama for example, prevent hooking! by another process ! or Dll injection and ...

Comment: Perhaps this is a result of your anti-malware software. Your program sounds like malware. We've only got your word that the hooking is fine and you gave no OS or Delphi version details.

Comment: And isn't the second parameter a DWORD?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I test this code in Windows 7 and 8.1 x86/x64 also my Delphi version is XE6. I test my code in a system without any anti-malware software too.

Comment: How do you know the correct signature for the function? We still don't know how you are hooking. And what does "any other command" mean?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I found the second param is PUlong
`NTSTATUS NTAPI DECLSPEC_HOTPATCH LdrLoadDll ( IN PWSTR SearchPath  OPTIONAL,
IN PULONG DllCharacteristics  OPTIONAL,
IN PUNICODE_STRING  DllName,
OUT PVOID *  BaseAddress 
) `

Comment: I think the second parameter is DWORD. Which one of us is right? You've given no citation. Here's my source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301727.aspx  And what does "any other command" mean?

Comment: What is a sustainable hook?

Comment: I found  correct signature in http://doxygen.reactos.org/d7/d55/ldrapi_8c_a7671bda932dbb5096570f431ff83474c.html .
I hooking using [delphi-hook-library](https://code.google.com/p/delphi-hook-library/)>

I meant from any command is for example :
`if szcwPath='aa' then szcwPath:='bb';`

Comment: @SertacAkyuz oh sorry i meant "Stable", Excuse me.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I change the second param to DWORD but have same result :(

Comment: You are thrashing around wildly.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I can't understand your meant from : You are thrashing around wildly !

Comment: I mean you are trying things at random without thinking hard enough. You did not take enough time to write a question with an MCVE. Why not?

Comment: I deleted my answer. I urge you to fix the question so that we can see your code and so understand what you are actually doing. You need to: 1. Add an MCVE. 2. Specify what this mysterious "other command" is. 3. Describe the failure in detail, "crashes" is never enough.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59008/discussion-between-user3725553-and-david-heffernan).

Comment: How did you define `PUnicodeString`? Why on earth can't we have an MCVE? I've just made one. It took me 10 minutes. Admittedly I know what I'm doing, but why can't you make an MCVE? And why are you ignoring all my questions?

Comment: OK, I restored my answer. I've found a couple more problems, and hooked the function myself. It's just fine so long as you don't expect to be able to call into arbitrary DLLs.

Comment: What version of Delphi are you using? Aren't you try to hook an x86 dll to an x64 process?

Comment: @mg30rg It's all in-proc

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks, I see now. I don't really see why does (s)he need hooking then, but that is another story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far as I can tell (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301727.aspx) the second parameter is actually a `DWORD`.

The other obvious problem is that the third parameter is not `PUnicodeString`. That is declared as `^UnicodeString`, a pointer to a Delphi Unicode string. You need the following:

```
type
  PUNICODE_STRING = ^UNICODE_STRING;
  UNICODE_STRING = packed record
    Length: Word;
    MaximumLength: Word;
    Buffer: PWideChar;
  end;
```

And then the functions should be declared like this:

```
var
  Old_LdrLoadDll: function(szcwPath: PWideChar; dwFlags: DWORD; pUniModuleName: 
    PUNICODE_STRING; pResultInstance: PPointer): NTSTATUS; stdcall;

function LdrLoadDll(szcwPath: PWideChar; dwFlags: DWORD; pUniModuleName: 
  PUNICODE_STRING; pResultInstance: PPointer): NTSTATUS; stdcall;
begin
  Result := Old_LdrLoadDll(szcwPath, pdwLdrErr, pUniModuleName, pResultInstance);
end;
```

Perhaps your crash comes when you attempt to read `pUniModuleName`.

Another other obvious problem that you might have is that you may end up calling code that is in a module that has not yet been loaded and is not ready to be called. Some modules are loaded on demand at runtime. For instance, see what happens when you call `ShowMessage`.

And yet another problem is that you can easily end up with a stack overflow if your `LdrLoadDll` calls functions that lead to recursive calls to `LdrLoadDll`. I encountered that when calling `MessageBox`.

The bottom line here is that you are probably safe to call functions in `kernel32`, but probably not much else. Remember that `LdrLoadDll` performs a very specific task and you must be careful to avoid disrupting that.

Comment: @d thanks David, I start hook when my app is started and in this time all modules was loaded .its very strange! Why the `OutputDebugString` work ? but other API calls not !

Comment: I'd imagined that you are hooking all processes. If you give partial details, expect us to make such assumptions.  Are there any more details that you might share with us? You might even tell us what "crashing" means. You could give us an MCVE. What's stopping you doing that?

Comment: The question title says "Applications crash" which indicates that other applications are crashing.

Comment: No i only hook processes of my app.
I meant from crash is : the program got a exception and then terminate (my english is bad and cant describe it any more) .

Comment: You can't describe the exception. Surely you can. There will have been a message and some addresses. Please try harder. You have not given enough detail. You'll need to edit the question. Please read back over all the comments. An MCVE is needed.

Comment: Thanks david , your code crash too ! (I'm trying to give you more details )

Comment: My code works fine. It does not crash for me in my program. So long as I'm careful what I call. You have to accept that calling functions in arbitrary modules is out. An hour ago I asked what "other command" you were calling. And still you have not answered. Why won't you let me help you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59009/discussion-between-user3725553-and-david-heffernan).